# C++ Reading and storing information from file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, storage

I have a text file that has the following data for a simple entry/exit system:

where each line has {time_stamp} {name} {door_entry} {status}

**time_stamp** - number of seconds since some arbitrary start time

**name** - The workers username

**door_entry** - door number entered/exited

**status** - whether they entered or exited the door

The text file is large and has about 10,000 entries similar to this

**Question:** I'm wondering how I can decompose each line and split each piece of information into a variable. So for example I have the Worker class here:

```
class Worker
{
    std::string staffToken;
    int doorEntry;
    std::string status;
    public:
        Employee();
};
```

I want to solve this problem with an array as well. I know I could use a Vector or a Map but I want to solve this with an array. 
I've created an array of pointer objects for the Worker class.

```
   typedef Worker * WorkPtr;
        WorkPtr * workers = new WorkPtr[MAX]; //where max is some large constant
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)  
        {
        workers[i] = new Worker();
        }
```

The goal of this problem I've created is that I simply want to check for any unusual activity in this text file where a Worker has entered or exited multiple times in a row:

Comment: There are lots of existing questions here about parsing text in C++. What specific part are you having trouble with? You've not asked a question (you made a statement about what you want to do).

Comment: Off topic: You may be over-using pointers here.You make an array of pointers to `Worker`, then fill the array of pointers with default constructed `Worker`s. You may get the same results with significantly less overhead and manual memory management with `Worker workers[MAX];` and no `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this template to split a string with a certain delimiter

```
template<typename Out>
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        *(result++) = item;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}
```

for example:

```
ifstream fin("your_file");
while(getline(fin,str))
{
    vector<string> res;
    res = split(str, ' ');
    //your process with res
}
```